# React opens website link after localhost url instead of https://websitelink

Tags: reactjs, react-link

I get employers web addresses from a database, when I click web address text it opens as localhost:3000/webadresslink, how can I change it to https://webaddresslink

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import EmployerService from '../../services/employerService'
import { Styles } from './style'
import { Card, Container } from 'react-bootstrap'

const EmployersList = () => {
  const [employers, setEmployers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    let employerService = new EmployerService()
    employerService.getAllEmployers().then(result => setEmployers(result.data.data))
  })
  return (
    <Styles>
      <Container>
        {
          employers.map(employer => (
            <Card>
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{employer.companyName}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                  <a href={employer.webAddress} target="blank">
                    {employer.webAddress}
                  </a>
                </Card.Text>
                <Card.Text>
                  {employer.email}
                </Card.Text>
                <Card.Text>
                  {employer.phoneNumber}
                </Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          ))
        }
      </Container>
    </Styles>
  )
}
```

Comment: What is the actual runtime value of `employer.webAddress`?

Comment: it comes "kodlama.io" as an example, my url when I click: http://localhost:3000/kodlama.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `kodlama.io` isn't an absolute URL.  It may *intuitively* look like one to you, but it isn't *structurally* any different from other relative URLs like:

- `index.html`
- `index.com`
- `index.html.com`
- `www.index.html`
- etc.

To tell the browser that this is a URL for a *different host* you'll need to prefix it:

- `https://kodlama.io`

Or even simply:

- `//kodlama.io`

If the data being displayed isn't well organized and *some* URL values have a prefix and *some* don't then a workable attempt at front-end logic could be simply: If the value doesn't contain "//" then prefix it with "//".  For example:

```
href={
  employer.webAddress.includes('//') ?
  employer.webAddress :
  `//${employer.webAddress}`
}
```

Comment: I really appreciated, thank you it worked!